# Ida pro doesn't demangle all function names

Tags: ida, c++

I am using Ida Pro 7.0 and working with a binary (firmware) written in C++ .Fortunately there are  symbols in the firmware and I know function names but Ida didn't manage to demangle all function names. I saw in the firmware ASCII string **gcc2**. Likely the binary was compiled using gcc2 compiler. There are a lot of important funcitons in the mangled form.

Help me out please. How Can I resolve this problem???

I tried to use idc.Demangle() func but unfortunately It can't demangle correctly.

P.S.
I found that ***c++filt*** utility works correctly

Comment: example names which are not being demangled?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Thank you Igor for your reply. I can't example the names. I'am in vacation. Can you describe the ways to do to resolve my problem. Maybe I need to play with Compiler submenu (Options->Compiler) or Demangled names. The only thing I remember that my device works under vxworks os.